# Minimising the expression $xy + yz + zx$ given constraints

Tags: inequality, optimization

I have a question in which I need to find the greatest lower bound of the cyclic sum $xy + yz + zx$ given the following constraints:

1) $x+y+z=k$ for some $k > 0$, and

2) $0 < x,y,z < \frac{k}{2}$.

I've tried Lagrange multipliers (in the vain hope that it would work, but it doesn't due to the extra constraint). I've tried manipulation but got nowhere, and direct substitution for $z$ using the first condition, but it reduces to a two-dimensional problem at best which I have no idea how to do.

Any hints would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $2(xy+xz+yz)=k^2-x^2-y^2-z^2$
so you are maximising the Euclidean distance from the origin to your
region. This region is a triangle with vertices
$(k/2,k/2,0)$, $(k/2,0,k/2)$, $(0,k/2,k/2)$ and the distance
to the origin is maximised at each of these.

Comment: Interesting, never thought of it that way at all for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$(x+y+z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy+2yz+2xz = k^2 $ 
 Since $x,y,z < \frac{k}{2}$, we have $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < \frac{3k^2}{4}$
 substituting this in the above equation we get, $$2(xy+yz+xz) > k^2 - \frac{3k^2}{4}\\ xy+yz+xz >\frac{k^2}{8}$$